# php oop. how to use variable freely?

Tags: php, class, oop

i having a problem in one of my code. im trying to learn how to do oop, but im stuck in understanding the principle of object.

im try to use variable tht i declare as private, and it predefine. i cant make it defined in function set.

```
class generateRandomString{
private $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
private $randomString = '';

private function setGenerateRandomString($length = 10){

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
}
public function getGenerateRandomString(){
    $this->setGenerateRandomString();
    return $this->$randomString;
}
}
```

and i dont understand either, why there is no clear explanation about this topic in internet about how to use class dynamically? or did i miss it? the tutorial and lesson that i found, all about the same thing, as of how to set, get, variable from out of class. i need help in how to fully utilize the class and function as im more into building a complex self-operate algorithm than building user-interact system.

and im totally new in class. sorry for asking.

Comment: `$this->characters`, and `$this->randomString`, without extra `$` sign

Comment: i did try '$characters = $this->$characters;' and '$randomString = $this->$randomString;'. tht wrong?

Comment: @dwerty_weird read carefully, no $ sign after the arrow.

Comment: @dwerty_weird: now please read my comment once again

Comment: I did not check your code or rewrite it to optimize, just modified it - http://pastebin.com/Hku9BddN  For example - second subsequent request will not erase data in `randomString`

Comment: @Cheery You should post it as an answer since it is the right way of using the variables. (your pastebin) :)

Comment: but i still get error as 'Undefined variable: characters in C:\wamp\www\IVS\script\server\enginefunction.php on line 40'

Comment: wait, @cherry, i found it. i miss another $ there... it work. ty. u should make it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your private set function, you are not referencing the correct variables.

Whenever you reference an object instance variable, you use `$this->variableName`.  So, in your `setRandomString( )` function call, you simply need to update the variables to the appropriate instance variables, like so:

```
private function setGenerateRandomString($length = 10){
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $this->randomString .= $this->characters[rand(0, strlen($this->characters) - 1)];
    }
}
```